# Can someone explain to me why the binding method doesn't work in these examples

Tags: javascript

In this example, when I add the bind method to the end of the function called deeper. the binding method doesn't work.

```
    var body = document.body;

function Depth() {

    this.state = "I am inside here";

    this.deep = function() {

        function deeper() {

            body.innerHTML = this.state;
        }.bind(this);

        deeper();
    }

}


var obj = new Depth();

obj.deep();
```

And in this example, when I add the bind method to the end of the new object that is calling the deep method. The binding method doesn't work.

```
    var body = document.body;

function Depth() {

    this.state = "I am inside here";

    this.deep = function() {

        function deeper() {

            body.innerHTML = this.state;
        }

        deeper();
    }

}


var obj = new Depth();

obj.deep().bind(this);
```

I already know what to do to make the function run properly and to print out the this.state code. But, I want some explanation as to why the first two examples do not work because those were the first ideas I had to write the code in. Here is the last example **that worked properly**.

```
var body = document.body;

function Depth() {

    this.state = "I am inside here";

    this.deep = function() {
        var state = this.state

        function deeper() {

            body.innerHTML = state;
        }

        deeper();
    }

}


var obj = new Depth();

obj.deep();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

['Function.prototype.bind()'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) returns a new method without changing the original method, so you have to assign the new method to a variable, and then you can use it:

```
    var deeper = function deeper() {

        body.innerHTML = this.state;
    }.bind(this);


    obj.deep = obj.deep.bind(this); // you can bind an object method, and then reassign it to the original property
```